# EP0282796B1 Is there an English version available?

Tags: translation

In reference to the patent: [EP0282796B1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP0282796B1)

Is this patent available in English? I cannot understand the e auto translation version.

Comment: Have you tried clicking the Espacenet link on the page you linked to?

Answer (score 0):

This granted EPO patent was published in German and has no English-language counterpart.
However it does have English-language claims:
https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/claims?CC=EP&NR=0282796B1&KC=B1&FT=D&ND=&date=19900905&DB=&locale=

Furthermore, you can use Chrome's built-in translator (right click and select "Translate to English") to translate the specification:
https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/description?CC=EP&NR=0282796B1&KC=B1&FT=D&ND=&date=19900905&DB=&locale=